# UEFI function running wrong part in if else

Tags: c, function, if-statement, uefi

I am writing a UEFI function which used to show status.

But when I give it a EFI_STATUS type "2" as "state" argument, it execute "else" part, instead of "state == 2" part.

I don't know which detail I missed.

```
EFI_STATUS ShowState(const CHAR16 * name, UINTN state) {
    if (state == 0) {
        Print(L"[ INFO ] %s success.\n", name);
    } else {
        CHAR16 * code;

        if (state == 1) {
            code = L"EFI_LOAD_ERROR";
        } else if (state == 2) {
            code = L"EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER";
        } else {
            code = L"Unknown";
        }
    
        if (code[0] == 'U') {
            Print(L"[ ERRO ] %s failed with [%d].\n", name, state);
        } else { // (code[0] == 'E')
            Print(L"[ ERRO ] %s failed with %s.\n", name, code);
        }
    }
    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER is not equal to 2. It is equal to 0x8000000000000002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read UEFI spec again, and as prl said, EFI_STATUS is a hex value, so we have some resolution:

- Use EFIERR(2) instead of 2
- Directly use EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER marco

And when I use `Print()` to print the status value, it only prints decimal "2",
that is the main reason which makes it confusing.

Edit: Thanks to MiSimon, now I know should use %r for print a status code.

Comment: Print is printing 2 because you are using %d as format specifier. I assume you are using a 64 bit platform and there %lu would be the correct format specifier. Like prl wrote EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER is != 2. If you are using edk2 there is the %r format specifier which prints the text that belongs to the error or warning code (like EFI_SUCCESS, EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER,...).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible errors here - either the state you send is wrong, or the test you made is wrong.
To test the state - add a print to show the state
to test your test - just always print the code.
so just add this line before the if:

```
Print(L"[ ERRO ] %s failed with [%d][%s].\n", name, state, code);
```

Also note that you're getting a UINTN for input, but talking about it as EFI_STATUS. an EFI_STATUS is a UINTN, but you need to make sure you passed the correct variable.

Or just post here the function the passes information to ShowState, plus the output you got